# how to change color of strokes in literally canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using the [Literally Canvas](http://literallycanvas.com/) widget and I want to make an `onclick` function that when triggered will change the color (`strokeStyle`) of what has already been drawn in the canvas element. I tried using:

```
lc.ctx.canvas.strokeStyle="red";
lc.ctx.canvas.style.strokeStyle="red";
lc.ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
```

There are tons of other objects and properties and I tried many more but I can't seem to get anywhere close, am I even in the right direction?. The only thing I tried that some how worked was using `lc.colors.primary = "red";`. It changed my stroking color to red but didn't change what has already been drawn, meaning I trigger the function and draw and the strokes are red but what has already been drawn stays black as it is.

Comment: @areiilla `lc` stands for the [Literally Canvas widget](http://literallycanvas.com). My edit is still in peer review ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Literally Canvas you can change the style of the **shapes** that are placed on the canvas.

You can access the shapes array by `lc.shapes`, grab an element and change it's color and afterwards call `repaintAllLayers()`. The `repaintAllLayers()` method is important to redraw the changes on to the canvas.

Unforunately the color properties are different for each kind of shape. Rectangles and circle use `strokeColor`, lines use `color` and for Pencil lines you have to change the `color` property of it's `smoothedPoints`. There may be other shapes with different color properties. So keep this as a starter.

Below you can find a snippet which demonstrates the behaviour. Because I haven't found a CDN for literallycanvas it is not working completely - you can only draw a line, then press the "Test" button and the line will appear in red.

```js
var lc = null;

function test() {
   for (var i=0; i<lc.shapes.length; i++) {
      if (lc.shapes[i].hasOwnProperty('smoothedPoints')) {
          // Pencil shapes
          for (var j=0; j<lc.shapes[i].smoothedPoints.length; j++) {
              lc.shapes[i].smoothedPoints[j].color = "red";
          }
      } else if (lc.shapes[i].hasOwnProperty('strokeColor')) {
          lc.shapes[i].strokeColor = "red";
      } else {
          // line shape
          lc.shapes[i].color = "red";
     }
   }
   lc.repaintAllLayers();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    lc = LC.init(
      document.getElementsByClassName('literally')[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<link href="http://literallycanvas.com/_static/lib/css/literallycanvas.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://literallycanvas.com/_static/lib/js/literallycanvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Draw a line, then press "Test" button
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<div class="literally"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work with my onclick function. When this code runs absolutely nothing happens. Although the color/strokeColor properties are added.

Comment: @TonyLee  Does the JavaScript console of your browser show some messages?

Comment: nope, but when I draw something onto the canvas and then manually put your code into the console and hit enter, it returns null.

Comment: @TonyLee I updated my answer and included a snippet. Please see my explanation on why literallycanvas will not work completely in this snippet.